# Oracle repository dependency for javers

Tags: oracle, audit, javers

I wanted to persist audit changes to oracle db. The micro-service is a spring boot application with hibernate. I found many dependencies in this link [mvn repository link for javers](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.javers/)

Which dependency should I be using for oracle db?

Comment: Please add a comment if you feel to downvote. I'd love to correct myself if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following dependency and it worked.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
            <artifactId>javers-spring-boot-starter-sql</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.13</version>
</dependency>
```

referred this link, [javers repository configuration link](https://javers.org/documentation/spring-boot-integration/#starter-repository-configuration)